Source map warning in next js
enter image description here
at the beginning of working with next ys there you have such problems, after 3 weeks it started to appear And don’t understand from VNAT some kind of error, I rummaged around and I realized that it’s SourceMap
I don't even know how to decide

contains unsupported "URL" field in one of its sections.

/** @type {import('next').NextConfig} */ const nextConfig = {   experimental: {     turbo: false, // Отключение Turbopack   },   webpack(config, { isServer }) {     if (!isServer) {       config.devtool = 'source-map'; // Настройка SourceMap для Webpack     }     return config;   }, }; 
export default nextConfig;
Chat GPT suggested this solution but I have NextJS turbopac there
